# Make Button shrink using CSS

Tags: css

I have a button that I want to give the appearance of being pressed, apart from the visual aspects, I would like to shrink the button by 1px all the way round, and maintain its position.

I've had numerous goes at this but can't seem to fathom it out.

Anyone help?

Comment: Can you share your code on JSFiddle ?

Comment: Yes, please share your code, also, when you say shrink by one pixel all round, I take it you mean when pressed, or it is currently too large?

Comment: It would be enough to shrink the font-size, the border and the padding, although there's also some CSS3 transformation property available.

Comment: If you want it to take 1px less space so it fits inline next to something else, without changing the look of the element in any way try `margin: -1px;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I've made a button which gives **Press** effect as well as it **shrinks** by a pixel without moving.

[**My Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/eytcN/1/)

HTML:

```
<input type="button" class="demo" value="Press Me" />​
```

CSS:

```css
.demo {
   background: #f5f5f5; /* Old browsers */
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #f5f5f5 0%, #dddddd 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
   background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#f5f5f5), color-stop(100%,#dddddd)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #f5f5f5 0%,#dddddd 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
   background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #f5f5f5 0%,#dddddd 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
   background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #f5f5f5 0%,#dddddd 100%); /* IE10+ */
   background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #f5f5f5 0%,#dddddd 100%); /* W3C */
   filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f5f5f5', endColorstr='#dddddd',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
   border: 1px solid #dddddd;
   padding: 5px;
   font-size: 18px;
   margin: 20px;
   cursor: pointer;
}

.demo:active {
   background: #dddddd; /* Old browsers */
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #dddddd 0%, #f5f5f5 99%); /* FF3.6+ */
   background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#dddddd), color-stop(99%,#f5f5f5)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #dddddd 0%,#f5f5f5 99%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
   background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #dddddd 0%,#f5f5f5 99%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
   background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #dddddd 0%,#f5f5f5 99%); /* IE10+ */
   background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #dddddd 0%,#f5f5f5 99%); /* W3C */
   filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#dddddd', endColorstr='#f5f5f5',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
   border: 1px solid transparent;
}
```

​

Answer (score 1):

I think for the "pressed" effect, you might want to change the padding instead of the size!

Like this:

```css
.MyButton {
    margin:10px 10px;    
    line-height:14px;
    font-size:14px;
    text-align:center;
    padding:3px 5px;
}

.MyButton:active {
    padding:3px 4px 3px 6px;
}
```

**With a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9vcNk/1/) here.** I think changing the padding looks better than resizing the button, not to mention that if you resize the button, you could also be changing the position of elements around it and that would look weird on the page.